# Rspec controller post request to render different partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, rspec, controller

I am trying to write a controller spec to test that the right partial is rendering after a post request.

Here is the controller method being posted to:

```
def lookup
@guest = Guest.where("mobile_number = ?", params[:lookup_mobile_phone_number]).first_or_initialize do |g|
  g.mobile_number = params[:lookup_mobile_phone_number]
end
if @guest.new_record?
  @visit = Visit.new(hotel_id: params[:hotel_id])
  render partial: "guests/form"
else
  @visit = Visit.new(guest_id: @guest.id, hotel_id: params[:hotel_id])
  render partial: "visits/form"
end
end
```

Here is the spec/controllers/guests_controller_spec.rb I wrote that is failing:

```
RSpec.describe GuestsController, :type => :controller do
describe "#lookup" do
render_views
let!(:returning_guest) { create(:test_guest) }
    context "when guest is already registered with hotel" do
      it "renders visits/form" do
        post :lookup, :guest => { :lookup_mobile_phone_number => "5553331212"}
        expect(response).to render_template(:partial => 'visits/form')
      end
   end
end
end
```

Here is the factory I'm using for :test_guest

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :test_guest, :class => 'Guest' do
    name 'Jack Guest'
    mobile_number '5553331212'
  end
end
```

This is the response I am getting when the test fails

```
 1) GuestsController#lookup when guest is already registered with hotel renders visits/form
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to render_template(:partial => 'visits/form')
     expecting partial <visits/form> but action rendered <["shared/_hotel_agent_name",     "_hotel_agent_name", "guests/_form", "_form"]>.
   Expected {"shared/_hotel_agent_name"=>1, "_hotel_agent_name"=>1, "guests/_form"=>1, "_form"=>1} to include "visits/form".
 # ./spec/controllers/guests_controller_spec.rb:16:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I've been hacking away at this a for a few days now, trying different approaches found on here with no luck. Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: In the error you can see the list of partials rendered: it renders `guests/form` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You send

```
post :lookup, :guest => { :lookup_mobile_phone_number => "5553331212"}
```

but in controller, you use

```
params[:lookup_mobile_phone_number]
```

not

```
params[:guest][:lookup_mobile_phone_number]
```

So to fix it, according to your controller, do

```
post :lookup, :lookup_mobile_phone_number => "5553331212"
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. That's a good point and a dumb mistake on my end. I made that tweak but it's still giving me the same exact error.

Comment: @NamNguyen You can debug it in a very simple way. Just add `raise Guest.all.inspect` or `raise params.inspect` as a first line in your controller and run your spec. By doing this, you'll check what params are incoming during test and if there is a `Guest` you are looking for in database.